# How to use this Message Module with Services Module?

Tags: 8, services

Can anyone tell me how to use [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) and [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module to create *REST API*? Is there any other module I need to install to make it work?

I am not sure but may be [Services Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_entity) module will work for me?

Comment: you may check the module page to check the dependency of these modules.